# What does the following mean from the meshech chochma?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, talmud-gemara

The Meshech Chochmah, Vaeschanan, Deuteronomy 6:5, says something which I don't understand. Here it is:

> וא"ל (ואמרי לה) לקיים מילי דנזיקין, כי האדם מדיני בטבע, ואוהב הקבוץ לרוב חסרונו.‏

Here is the entire part:

> בכל לבבך וכו'. האי מאן דבעי למיהוי חסידא - לקיים מילי דברכות (בבא קמא ל.). זה הדבקות וההכרה שהכל בא מן השם וההודאה אליו, וזה "בכל לבבך" על השכליות. ואמרי לה לקיים מילי דאבות, זה מדות ותכונת הנפש וזה "בכל נפשך", וא"ל ואמרי לה לקיים מילי דנזיקין, כי האדם מדיני בטבע, ואוהב הקבוץ לרוב חסרונו. וכבר נתעורר בן זומא (ברכות נח.) בראותו אוכלסא אמר כל מה שברא וכו'. אדה"ר אדם הראשון כמה יגיעות יגע. ואינו דומה לבע"ח לבעל חי שלבושו וביתו עמו, וחכם הרזים שמשתלם בדיעה ובחכמה ע"י על יד חינוך זולתו, לכן מה דעלך סני (שבת לא.), מה שאתה רוצה מזולתך תועליות ולא רע, כן את לזולתך. וזה ובכל מאודך עם מה שיש לך היתרון על כל הבע"ח בעל החי, וזה מילי דנזיקין. ודו"ק ודייק ותמצא קל.‏

Answer (score 3):

> And some say that [in order to be pious] one should keep the laws of damages. For man is naturally social, and loves to be in a group, due to his many deficiencies.